# Joyride Instructions for first time login user only

Tags: javascript

I want to guide users when they login for the first time. I am planning to do it with joyride module. Right now, I can either show a link in a block or can start it automatically as the page is accessed. Please suggest me a way to guide only authenticated users after they first login and never after.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked this https://www.drupal.org/node/245209 ?

Comment: this is to redirect on first login, but i want the home page to be same for everyuser, other wise, is there any way to clone the homepage on some other page?

Comment: If you need role based home page you can use this https://www.drupal.org/project/front